# Login com retrofit android

Tags: android, web-service, login, retrofit

Oi fiz uma pergunta e não souberam me ajudar, tenho um *webservice* que está fazendo um *get* que quando inserido o nome do usuário ele irá permitir o acesso dele ao aplicativo e assim vai passar o usuário para o próxima tela.

Esse é o código:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String PREFS_USER = "Preferencia";
    EditText user;
    Button salvar;
    EditText password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.senha);

        salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.salvar);
        salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_USER, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("PrefUser", user.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("PrefPass", password.getText().toString());

                //Confirma a gravação dos dados
                editor.commit();

                loadJson(user.getText().toString());

            }
        });

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_USER, 0);
        user.setText(settings.getString("PrefUser", ""));
        password.setText(settings.getString("PrefPass", ""));
    }

    public void loadJson(String usuario){

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://"+getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("PrefHost", "") +":8080/FazendaWebservice/webresources/fazenda/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        AcessoClient client = retrofit.create(AcessoClient.class);
        Call<Acesso> call = client.reposForUsuario(usuario);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Acesso>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Acesso> call, Response<Acesso> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Acesso> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "         Erro ao estabelecer conexão"+ "\n"+"            Verifique o host inserido"+"\n"+"Por favor tente novamente mais tarde!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Classe `Acesso`:

```
public class Acesso {

    private String nomeusuario;
    private String senhausuario;
    private String listaprodutos;
    private String vendasonline;

    public String getNomeusuario() {
        return nomeusuario;
    }

    public void setNomeusuario(String nomeusuario) {
        this.nomeusuario = nomeusuario;
    }

    public String getSenhausuario() {
        return senhausuario;
    }

    public void setSenhausuario(String senhausuario) {
        this.senhausuario = senhausuario;
    }

    public String getListaprodutos() {
        return listaprodutos;
    }

    public void setListaprodutos(String listaprodutos) {
        this.listaprodutos = listaprodutos;
    }

    public String getVendasonline() {
        return vendasonline;
    }

    public void setVendasonline(String vendasonline) {
        this.vendasonline = vendasonline;
    }
}
```

Classe `AcessoClient`:

```
public interface AcessoClient {
    @GET("Acesso/get/{usuario}")
    Call <Acesso> reposForUsuario(
            @Path("usuario") String usuario
    );
}
```

JSON retornado do *WebService*

```
{"nomeusuario":"admin","senhausuario":"yMJsiuiTcpC","listaprodutos":"S","vendasonline":"S"}
```

Não estou sabendo o que colocar dentro do onResponse pra ele acabar fazendo a validação, alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Validar acesso com retrofit android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235258/validar-acesso-com-retrofit-android)

Comment: Cara não é duplicata de nada, não resolveram meu problema estou tentando, fizeram esse esquema de duplicata lá, mas o outro código tinha nada a ver com o meu

Comment: não será fazendo diversas vezes a mesma pergunta que irá resolver :), para isso existe o editar, para caso alguém não entenda a sua explicação você poder melhorar ela, ficar fazendo a mesma perguntas diversas vezes pode até ser interpretado  como um spam e ocasionar um possível banimento ou limitação na sua conta. Você fez a mesma pergunta(mudou as palavras), e copiou o mesmo código resultado sim é duplicada

Comment: Entendi, tudo bem, você sabe como me ajudar?

Comment: Entenda @RenatoCrispim que uma duplicata de pergunta é alguma questão que tem relevancia ou que aborde o mesmo tema que a sua. Dificilmente a duplicata da pergunta vai ter o mesmo codigo que seu questionamento, mas as respostas das mesmas podem te guiar na resolução do problema.

Comment: Sim eu sei, e eu pesquisei e testei o outro código mudei ele e não me levou a nada... Mas já resolvi obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiramente você tem que "serializar" as variáveis da sua classe `Acesso`. Veja um exemplo:

```
public class Acesso implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2161110911377686463L;

    @SerializedName("nomeusuario")
    private String nomeusuario;

    @SerializedName("senhausuario")
    private String senhausuario;

    // restante do seu código aqui... 
}
```

Sendo também preciso alterar método `loadJson()` para receber os valores referente ao usuário e senha.

```
public void loadJson(final String usuario, final  String password){
    // restante do conteúdo aqui...
}
```

Sendo assim, finalizando, para receber as informações dentro do `onResponse` você usa o `response.body()`. Veja um exemplo:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Acesso>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Acesso> call, Response<Acesso> response) {

         Acesso acesso = response.body();

         // essa condição compara os valores do webservice
         // com os valores que você está passando por parâmetro
         if(acesso.getNomeusuario().equals(usuario) 
               && acesso.getSenhausuario.equals(password)){
             // se entrou aqui, as credenciais estão corretas

             // aqui você será redirecionado para uma classe qualquer
             // que deseja ir usando o Intent
             Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Entrou.class);
             startActivity(i);
         } else {
             // se entrou aqui, ou a nome de usuário ou password
             // estão incorretas
         }             
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Acesso> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Erro ao estabelecer conexão"+ "\n"+"            Verifique o host inserido"+"\n"+"Por favor tente novamente mais tarde!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Então cara o que eu não to conseguindo é fazer o onrespons

 Acesso acesso = response.body();
         // Aqui a baixo você já terá preenchido a variável
         // acesso, no qual você poderá fazer a validação
         // de acesso do usuário.

Essa parte não to sabendo fazer, sou novo no android

Comment: @RenatoCrispim Você sabe debugar o código?! As informações realmente chegará no `response.body()`... Você tem que debugar e verficar o que está chegando pra você no `resnponse.body()`;

Comment: Eu sei debugar, mas acontece que dps Acesso acesso = response.body(); eu não tenho nenhum código entende?

Comment: @RenatoCrispim seria interessante você colocar no seu código a classe Acesso e também o resultado que está chegando do seu webservice. Senão fica difícil brow, sem uma bola de cristal.

Comment: Ok vou editar e colocar ele aqui, mas debugando ele, ele busca o usuario que eu quero, só não ta passando a pagina

Comment: @RenatoCrispim Não vai passar enquanto você não colocar uma condição pra passar. Pra eu fazer isso pra você, preciso que você edite e coloque as duas informações que te pedi. A classe `Acesso` e o resultado que retorna do webservice.

Comment: Está editado, será que já consegue?

Comment: @RenatoCrispim a segunda informação que pedi você não colocou na pergunta. Seria o JSON que retorna do servidor.

Comment: Esse é o ip: http://192.168.25.212:8080/FazendaWebservice/webresources/fazenda/Acesso/get/admin

e esse é o que ele retorna

{"nomeusuario":"admin","senhausuario":"yMJsiuiTcpC","listaprodutos":"S","vendasonline":"S"}

Comment: @RenatoCrispim coloque na pergunta por favor.

Comment: Já coloquei, está no final

Comment: Conseguiu ver cara ?

Comment: @RenatoCrispim isso ai funciona pra mim sempre. Boa sorte.

Comment: Não entendi, como assim funciona pra você sempre?

Comment: Eu estou tentando colocar esse código dentro do onResponse:    Acesso acesso = response.body();

               if (acesso.getNomeusuario() == user.getText().toString()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuário : " + user.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, BuscaActivity.
               }class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

Comment: @RenatoCrispim estou querendo dizer que é desta forma como te mostrei é como eu faço nas minhas aplicações.

Comment: Funcionou obrigado.